# insert Data From Table in Another Data-Source

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, datasource

I Create Table in Ax 2012 with two Fields (ReportName , FileLocation) to insert into them the Reports Names

from Report Server Data-source

so I use the Following Script 
[image: Insert Data With Errors]
How Can i Complete the Insert of Data ??

Regards.

Comment: the error states it clearly: you also need to set the RECID field

Comment: ReportNameKey doesn't accept the Null values but 'Name' From Catalog contains NULL values. Plus Set some default value for RECID

Answer (score 0):

What is unclear about the comment?  You can avoid `NULL`s by including a value for the other column:

```
insert into reportnamekey (reportname, filelocation)
    select c.reportname, ''
    from reportserver.dbo.catalog c;
```

I doubt that you want a file location to be an empty string.  The location is probably another field in `catalog`.  However, this will fix the error and give you an idea of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can either make the **RECID** column NULLABLE or insert a default value for it.

Comment: I tried To make it NULLABLE but it give me an Error For that and didn't Save

Comment: Can you provide the error it gave when you tried to make it nullable.